# Libxml++: Returning Line/Column number upon validity errors

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, libxml2

I'm writing a simple C++ program to parse a XML file to check if it is well formatted, and if it is valid against a schema supplied. I'm restricted to using Libxml++ as per software lead's constraints.

I got everything working and now trying to work on error handling such that it returns a more meaningful error message. In parsing errors this is already done for me as it returns the line and column number where the parsing issue occurred. However on Validity exceptions, it just states the element the validity error was caught and a short message regarding what's wrong.

**Is it possible to modify this such that it also returns the line and column number this was encountered**? Problem is that if validity error was caught against an element that is NOT UNIQUE, it will be rather extraneous to find it if the XML file is thousands of lines long.

I'm using a DomParser to parse the XML, and using the SchemaValidator class as seen in libxml++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible with *libxml++*, but you can use the underlying *libxml2* functions directly. The key is to register a structured error handler with [xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlschemas.html#xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors). The error handler receives an [xmlError](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlerror.html#xmlError) which contains a field for the line and column number. The column is stored in `int2`. See the following example program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/xmlschemas.h>

void errorHandler(void *userData, xmlErrorPtr error) {
    printf("Error at line %d, column %d\n%s",
           error->line, error->int2, error->message);
}

int main() {
    xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr pctxt = xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt("so.xsd");
    xmlSchemaPtr schema = xmlSchemaParse(pctxt);
    xmlSchemaValidCtxtPtr vctxt = xmlSchemaNewValidCtxt(schema);
    xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors(vctxt, errorHandler, NULL);
    xmlSchemaValidateFile(vctxt, "so.xml", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Given a schema `so.xsd`

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="doc">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="attr" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="uniq">
        <xs:selector xpath="item"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@attr"/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

and a document `so.xml`

```xml
<doc>
    <item attr="one"/>
    <item attr="two"/>
    <item attr="three"/>
    <item attr="one"/>
</doc>
```

the program prints

```
Error at line 5, column 23
Element 'item': Duplicate key-sequence ['one'] in unique identity-constraint 'uniq'.
```